# Error unsupported on-disk structure for file ... found 11.1, support 12.0

Tags: c#, .net, firebird

Is it possible to connect to v2.5 and v3 server with the same client?
I'm using Firebird .Net client 5.11.
When I open the v3 database everything's working.
When I open the v2.5 database I receive the following exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' > occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
>
> Additional information: unsupported on-disk structure for file
>   C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\FIREBIRD DATABASES\FIREBIRD_V2\MY.FDB;
>   found 11.1, support 12.0

**EDIT**
The real case:
I have a server running Firebird v2.5;
I have a server running Firebird v3;
(I can't change this configuration; they are not running my applications)

I need data from both servers from a C# .Net application.
Is there a way to connect to both servers using the same ADO .Net Provider?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not about the client connecting to different Firebird servers (which works fine), the problem is the Firebird server opening an unsupported database ODS (On-Disk Structure) version. The error means that you tried to open a Firebird 2.1 database (ODS 11.1) with Firebird 3. Firebird 3 only supports ODS 12, Firebird 2.5 supports ODS 10 - 11.2 (which are the ODS versions for InterBase 6.0, Firebird 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.1 and 2.5).

There are two options:

1. Install Firebird 2.5 next to Firebird 3 and run it on a different port than the default. Connect to this server if you want to use the database in the older ODS format.
2. Backup the database using Firebird 2.5 (or 2.1) with the `gbak` tool of that version, and restore it under Firebird 3 with the `gbak` tool of that version. This will create a database with ODS 12. The database can no longer be used under an earlier Firebird version

Comment: "Firebird 2.5 supports ODS 10 - 11.2" - I guess actually it starts with ODS 9. At least I am perfectly sure Yaffil and FB 2.1 support IB5 db. (yes, I was shocked when our client came to us with such a setup :-D )

Comment: @Arioch'The To be honest I only mentioned InterBase 6.0 because its ODS 10 is the same as Firebird 1.0/1.5. I'm not 100% sure if Firebird 2.5 did not remove support for ODS 9 and I really don't care enough about ancient InterBase versions to find out.

Comment: Please see my edit above. The servers are not mine so I can't upgrade/downgrade one of them. I need to connect to them using only one C# .Net client. (Someone changed the title of the question so it was not clear)

Comment: @bubi But you are wrong about having two servers. The error indicates you are opening a Firebird 2.1 database (ODS 11.1) with a Firebird 3 server (which only supports ODS 12). That means that you are always connecting to a Firebird 3 server. So either you only have Firebird 3, or you are connecting to the wrong TCP/IP port if both Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3 are running on that server. For your information: The Firebird ADO.net provider can connect to Firebird 1.0 and higher (including the development versions of Firebird 4).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right. I misconfigured the testing environment. Everything is working with the same .Net provider.

Comment: @bubi So if you do have both Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3 running on the same host, then in their configuration they should be using different TCP/IP ports. You will need to specify that port explicitly in your connection string (property `port` or `port number`), if the server uses a different value than the default of 3050.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  THANKS!!!!!
I exactly forgot to insert the ports in the connection string. The .Net client v5.11 can connect to both v2.5 and v3 servers. Similar behaviour using DBeaver. Now the question is, why with DBeaver I can choose between "Firebird" and "Firebird 3.x" JayBird drivers? But this is another question... Thanks!

Comment: @bubi I don't know, there is no difference for Jaybird either. Looking at the entry in DBeaver, they have somehow made the assumption that Jaybird 2.2 is not for Firebird 3 (or Jaybird 3.x is not for earlier versions), so they added a new entry for Firebird 3.x that uses Jaybird 3.0.3 (which works fine with Firebird 1.0 and higher)...

Answer (score 1):

It's because your are using a 2.5.x database file(fdb file) in a 3.x firebird server. If you use docker, you can pull 2.5.7 version [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jacobalberty/firebird/tags). And start docker with command `docker run --name firebird -p 3050:3050 --mount source=data,destination=/firebird/data/ jacobalberty/firebird`

You should put your fdb file under /var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data